# Future of AWT and Swing?

Tags: java, asp.net, swing, awt

I am about to learn a subject as an elective which will teach me AWT, Swing and little bit knowledge regarding threads (in Java). As on Stackover Overflow mostly there are working professionals, I would like to ask:

1. Are there any need to learn these basics of Java in industry?
2. Are these technologies are already outdated?
3. Which one will be wiser to choose: Advance concepts of Java or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, In the mainstream, desktop GUIs will be replaced with new generation rich web frameworks like GWT or Wicket.

1) Knowing Swing will give you big advangate when learning e.g. GWT.
   IMO (unlike most), Swing is mostly well designed OOP model for GUI.
   The concepts will live for an era.

2) See 1). Technology will become non-mainstream, but still live in desktop apps and old enterprise rich clients. But the concepts will prevail.

3) Not a real question, you'll get pyloried :)  But I'd go for Java any time without any second guess.

Comment: Getting really mixed opinion by everyone, However I am bit concern about future of Tablet PC, Because learning Swing and AWT is just waste of money in tablets. Thanks for your opinion mate!

Comment: It's true that Rich Internet Applications are displacing traditional desktop apps (Swing based). However there's still a lot of commercial Java code out there, so plenty of job security for years to come :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to choose java. Keeping the answer close to your questions.

1) Yes, Basics of java are important irrespective of whether they are used in industry or not. For example: You may learn to write code for swings but in the industry you might use some drag and drop mechanism for the same but even so, one would consider you as a software developer only if you are strong in basics.

2) No, java technologies are not outdated, not yet at least. Many software industries rely on java as a platform to develop products because of various reasons. Its good performance, availability of java developers, et al.

3) Advanced concepts of java IMO is better compared to asp.net for a learner. Asp.net will restrict you to Microsoft's platform and later on you might be bound to streamline your career learning Microsoft's technologies like C# etc. J2EE, JSP and the rest of the advanced java concepts will give you a strong foothold in web application development. Having learnt Advanced java thoroughly it is easier to switch to Asp.net but not necessarily vice versa.

Having learnt java thoroughly, you will get acquainted with various facets of OOP, Web application development and many other basics of programming. Shifting onto any other language/platform will be easy, once you are thorough with programming concepts in java.

Comment: Thanks for a really descriptive answer VeeKay, As I said one of the comments on Ondra's answer...Getting really mixed opinions, I might stick to this subject as Threading is an important feature to learn. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Just for avoiding trolls.

In order to anwser the third point.

Advance Java (using Spring, Struts and stuffs) or using ASP.Net (MVC3) is quite similar in several ways. So both is ok, the choice should be driven by the fact your company is using more .net or java.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise that you learn about threads. That's essential basic knowledge. I would expect any Java professional to be proficient in the basics of multi-threaded programming, and the concepts behind it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know - for junior Java EE dev, threads aren't necessary - or at least, shouldn't be :) But true, not knowing them is kind of fatheaded.

Comment: But any comp sci grad should have this hammered in anyway. I know we were bored silly with dining philosophers and locking strategies etc.